# Best Seller Logic - Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, best-seller

How does Magento 2 pick up the best seller products? What is the logic behind that? (I have the code ,  but want to know the logic)

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic behind that number of product quantity order most is bestseller product.

You can also see on line **138**

Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers.php

```
'qty_ordered' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(order_item.qty_ordered)')
```